# Error while deleing data from google cloud bucket using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to delete the bucket data from google cloud bigquery as:

```
        prefix = '122352346' + '202106'
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('test-bucket')
        bucket.delete_blobs(blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))
```

The bucket is present and it also has the prefix 122352346202106

While executing, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/bigquery/bigquery_data.py", line 205, in execute
    bucket.delete_blobs(blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 1622, in delete_blobs
    len(blobs),
TypeError: object of type 'HTTPIterator' has no len()
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the blob iterator differently:

```
    prefix = '122352346' + '202106'
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('test-bucket')

    for blob_to_delete in bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix):
        bucket.delete_blobs(blob_to_delete)
```

Answer (score 0):

**blobs** parameter in [delete_blobs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.delete_blobs) looks for a list type containing the blob names to delete.

If you look at the type of the object you are passing to the blobs parameter, it's not a list type but "google.api_core.page_iterator.HTTPIterator".

Hence, this will do the job:

```
bucket.delete_blobs(blobs=list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='sample/path')))
```